# How to search home directory with an extension of html

Tags: unix

How can i write a single command line that a user might enter to search their home directory for all files with an extension of html?

Comment: This looks like a homework. As all your other questions do.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest implementation of that would be to issue:

`dir *.html` in Windows, and `ls *.html` in Unix-derived operating systems such as Linux

Where the star, or asterisk (*the character's name, what literally means little star in Greek, starlet*), is a catch-all character for all preceding characters or the entire string before the dot and four terminal letters otherwise the extension (`.html` that is)

With the variants of `dir /s /b *.html` in Windows, if you want a **b**are format, that is just list output, instead of time, date, and file type (directory, symlink or so) in colons, and to to do a recursive search meaning search files with the extension in **s**ubdirectories, that is other folders inside the folder, and in their *children*.

Answer (score 0):

Find will do this for you.

```
find ~ -name '*.html*'
```

Comment: `find ~ -type f -iname "*.html"`

Comment: Why the trailing `*` on the search patter? The questioner wasn't looking for files with names ending in `.htmlx`, etc. It might, though, be worth mentioning `-iname` in case he also wants to find `.HTML` files (and other capitalisations).

Comment: @Hydranix - My comment crossed with yours: good idea to add the `-type f` clause.

Comment: @AFH I like your explanation, which mine lacked.

Comment: @Hydranix do you want me to edit mine to match yours - I was sure there was nicer options to pass to find, but at the time was dealing a hungry son and so gave the simplest.

Comment: @djsmiley2k late reply, but there's no need to edit your unless you feel the need. My example is just more thorough of a search.